# How to Pass Values from MTM to Data Driven coded Ui Test case?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, coded-ui-tests, data-driven-tests

I am new to Coded UI.
I Have created data Driven coded UI test Case.I am Passing .CSV file as a data source. We have uploaded that Coded UI testcase into TFS. After Integrating Coded UI test Automated Build With MTM, It Runs fine from MTM for the values passed in .CSV file before automatic build created using VS2012.
Now my question is Is is possible to Pass Values to Automatic Coded UI in above scenario from MTM so that testers dont have to modify .CSV files from Visual studio? If Yes, Can anyone Please Guiid Me How?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible. Here is an example line of what you will need to have at the top of your function. (Note that the TestMethod Attribute is contained within it) This line should replace the Datasource line that you have for your .CSV file.

```
[DataSource("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.TestCase", "[InsertURLToCollectionHere];[InsertProjectNameHere]", "[InsertTestCaseNumber]", DataAccessMethod.Sequential), TestMethod]
```

Once you get that in your code you should be able to add the parameters to your TestSteps in MTM by adding the text of "@[InsertNameOfParameterHereWithoutSpaces]". At this point your Test cases should pull the data from MTM instead of your .CSV file.

Comment: Thanks for your reply spam1923. I have replaced DataSource line with the one you have provided. Then i created automated build for the same project.I have imported those test cases using tcm.exe to MTM. when i open that test case in MTM, there is no action mentioned as i am directly importing all the test cases created in VS2012. i have created blank action and added 2 parameters(For Login test case) as Username and Password. Provided Values to Them. But still if i run the test case, It recieves values from CSV only. Can you please help????

Comment: When you use your parameters in the test case do you use this format? TestContext.DataRow["Username"].ToString(); Also, you mentioned you created an automated build for the same project. Did you assign the new build to your Test plan?

Comment: Yes. I am using **TestContext.DataRow["Username"].ToString()** in my coded UI code to access the parameters of CSV File.  Also I have assigned new build defination to my test plan.

Comment: When you run the test in VisualStudio instead of MTM, after changing the datasource, does the test pull values from the CSV or MTM? It should still pull them from MTM whether it is linked or not. If that part works it might help limit down where the error is. Assuming that works there is probably some issue in how the TestCase in MTM is linked to the TestMethod in VS. Here is the method I used to link the test cases to MTM [MSDN: Automate a test case in Microsoft Test Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380741.aspx).

Comment: Hi Spam1923, Problem is solved. I think i didnt updated the build after editing the DataSource .Silly Mistake. Thanks for the help.